# Как правильно разобрать XML если в тексте внутри тэгов есть переносы строк?

Tags: xml

Есть XML файл, содержащий следующую конструкцию:

```
<text>
Какой-то текст
в две строки
</text>
```

Если строго следовать спецификации, то как должно быть прочитано содержимое элемента <text>?

A) `'Какой-то текст в две строки'`
Б) `#32'Какой-то текст в две строки'#32`
B) `#10'Какой-то текст'#10'в две строки'#10`
Г) `'Какой-то текст'#10'в две строки'`
L) Другой вариант (какой)?

[Спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/) читал, но с тем количеством перекрёстных ссылок и моим знанием английского однозначного ответа так и не нашел.

Comment: А какими средствами планируется производить разбор XML? Язык программирования, библиотеки какие желаете использовать при решении этой задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соответствующие абзацы ссылок особо и не содержат:

> In editing XML documents, it is often convenient to use "white space"
>   (spaces, tabs, and blank lines) to set apart the markup for greater
>   readability. Such white space is typically not intended for inclusion
>   in the delivered version of the document. On the other hand,
>   "significant" white space that should be preserved in the delivered
>   version is common, for example in poetry and source code.
>
> **An [XML processor](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#dt-xml-proc) must always pass all characters in a document that
>   are not markup through to the application.**

---

Перевожу:

> При редактировании XML-документов зачастую удобно использовать
>   "пробельные символы" (пробелы, табуляцию, пустые строки) для отделения
>   разметки с целью улучшить читаемость. Эти "пробельные символы" обычно
>   не предназначены для включения в поставляемую версию документа. С
>   другой стороны, часто встречаются и значимые пробельные символы,
>   которые нужно сохранять, к примеру в стихах или программном коде.
>
> **Все пробельные символы, не относящиеся непосредственно к разметке, должны быть переданы приложению в разобранных XML-процессором
>   данных.**

(Правда, [есть детали касательно нормализации нестандартных переводов строк в единичный `\n`/`#xA`/10](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#sec-line-ends), спасибо [@ru-volt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14963/ru-volt))

Разметкой в данном случае являются только теги, ограничиваемые угловыми скобками, посему в тексте всё, что находится между концом открывающего тега `>` и началом закрывающего `<`, включая пробельные символы, должно быть сохранено.

Собственно, `libxml` (дёрнутый из Ruby через Nokogori) так и делает:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
Nokogiri::XML(<<XML).first_element_child.text
<text>
Какой-то текст
в две строки
</text>
XML
```

---

```ruby
"\nКакой-то текст\nв две строки\n"
```

Здесь Ruby показывает строки с экранированием, `\n` это "символ новой строки", а двойные кавычки являются частью представления, не частью данных. Технология, которую используете вы, может такие строки отображать иначе.

Comment: Еще может оказаться релевантным вот этот абзац:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#sec-line-ends
Грубо говоря "все переводы строк строк транслировать в обычный line feed"

Comment: Это я видел. Там ещё для атрибутов написано что все переводы заменяются пробелами и в начале и конце удаляются. А для обычного текста я так и не нашёл. Да, похоже что всё-таки вариант В, спасибо.

Comment: @Alekcvp а этот конкретный случай нет смысла описывать отдельно, если более общего правила достаточно.

Comment: @D-side Да, но есть нюансы, например #xD#xA заменяется на #xA перед чтением файла, и эта нормализация неявно нарушает выделенный текст.

Comment: @Alekcvp и да, и нет, ссылку добавил. Но в конечном счёте, переводы строк остаются переводами строк, просто заменяются на стандартные. Но да, это уже "не совсем те символы". Спокойствия ради можно использовать только `#xA` :)

Comment: Кстати, как выяснилось, IE нифига не по стандарту xml отображает...

Comment: @Alekcvp у IE ворбще на удивление много своих стандартов, о которых никто не знает, к сожалению .-. С другой стороны, зачем сырой XML смотреть в IE глазами? Формат же не для человеческого глаза предназначен.